# Создание запуска приложения java для "недалеких" пользователей

Tags: java

Есть jar-архив с приложением java. Нужно сделать так, чтоб пользователь мог запускать приложение не из командной строки, а просто кликнул по ярлыку и всё запустилось (под винду). Как это сделать? Написать и скомпилировать программу например на C#, которая будет делать java -jar app.jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто написать bat-файл, например, start.bat, а в нём то, что Вы и написали java -jar <ваш jar-файл>.jar

Comment: Это решение я нашел, и скорее всего им и воспользуюсь. Но хотелось бы чтоб на каждой машине этот bat создавался автоматически. Как это сделать? Инсталлятор какой то нужен. Какие решения практикуются на сегодняшний день? Чтоб юзер установил, как любую софтину и пользовался. Пусть даже только из винды.
Хотя если писать инсталлятор, то можно генерить либо bat либо sh файл под *nix

Comment: Вообще много всякого софта для этого, например:<br/>
http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/02/programming/install-simple-free-installation-package-creator.html
http://all-for-rus.narod.ru/install.htm

Comment: @dude а .bat и .jar должны лежать в одной папке?

Answer (score 4):

создаем runjar.bat файл следующего содержания:

```
@echo off
@java -jar %*
```

на windows 7 сделал так:
Start -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a program

для jar файла указываем путь к runjar.bat файлу.

jar file для проверки:

```
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
HelloWorld.class
```

содержимое манифеста:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

java source:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame ;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame ( "Hello world" ) ;
        f.setSize ( 200, 200 ) ;
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) ;
        f.setVisible ( true ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы даже можете сделать ярлык для `Java.exe` с необходимыми параметрами запуска. Ярлыки как-то эстетичнее батников.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ucware.com/jexec/

http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, удобнее настроить запуск jar-файлов средствами системы (в Windows - "Свойства" - "Изменить приложение" --> "Java Platform binary" (java(w).exe)). Как вариант. Не создавать же ярлык рядом с каждым jar - файлом.

Comment: Мы же создаем для пользователей ярлык на рабочем столе и в главном меню для каждой программы.

Comment: Видимо у нас разные понятия о "недалеких" пользователях. Не думаю, что кто-то будет так заморачиваться.

Answer (score 0):

создаём .reg файл, а в нем строку на добавления типа .jar которое нужно запускать java.exe с параметром -jar "%1"

в итоге все jar файлы буду запускаться как нужно. Виндовс сейчас под рукой нету, так что точное решение подсказать не могу. Но думаю если вы погуглите то найдете его.