# NetBeans Desktop Application

Tags: java, netbeans

Наверно, щас задам мегаламерский вопрос, но всё-таки:
"Как запустить Desktop Application, созданное в Net Beans на java, не из самой среды, а типа из exe-шника".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После построения java-проекта netbeans в каталоге yourApplication/dist генерирует jar-архив и файл README.TXT, в котором описано что и как делать. Вообще там ничего нового не написано разумеется просто `java -jar "yourApplication.jar"` Так и запускать. Вы ещё что-то про exe говорили. Посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76122/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-java-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9). Мне дали массу ответов, если это то, что Вам нужно. Или [сюда](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=914488) лучше.

Answer (score 3):

На самом то деле, вопрос далеко не мегаламерский: запуск десктопного Java приложения как обычного приложения в оси это не так то просто как кажется.

Действительно рекомендованный способ это запуск через исполняемый JAR. Все было бы замечательно, но для запуска требуется наличие JVM (или проще говоря установленного JRE). В реальном мире есть много компов где нет установленного JVM - как быть в таком случае? Обертка JAR в exe это тоже не выход, поскольку это всего лишь способ загрузки JAR в JVM и не более того.

Есть 2 выхода:

1. Обернуть JAR в умный [MSI инсталлятор](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html), который установит приложение стандартными средствами оси и при необходимости скачает и установит JVM
2. Сконвертировать Java приложение из байткодов в нативные для оси инструкции. Есть такие специальные AOT (ahead of time) компиляторы. По сути они берут Java байткод и преобразовывают в машинный код нужной платформы. Обзор [таковых здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler). В общем в итоге получается настоящий EXE'шник (если говорим о Windows) для запуска которого не требуется JVM

Comment: это уже танцы с бубном начались, если джава - значит джар, и не надо говорить, что если на машине нету явы - это проблема для пользователя. Имхо, такие рассуждения как-то отводят от самой идеи универсальности джавы с ее платформонезависимостью =)

Comment: Я как раз так не говорил. Если на машине JVM нет, то это очевидно проблема разработчика, но никак не юзера. Именно представленные варианты и дают некое пространство выбора для разработчика

Comment: не согласен, если ты разработчик - ты пишешь программу, например игру на С++, а я - пользователь, если хочу в нее поиграть я уже должен заботится о ее запуске, если я сижу под юниксом, то должен поставить эмулятор или перейти на виндовс, ты конечно можешь ее портировать под другие системы и подсказать мне как ее правильно запустить, но ты не должен изначально делать ее универсальной.

Answer (score 2):

Есть [JSmooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSmooth) как вариант. Он оборачивает jar в exe-шник

**UPD.**
Погуглил, нашёл ещё [этот инструмент](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Cамый простой способ это создать ".bat" файл на рабочем столе примерно следующего содержимого:

```
java -cp <classpath> <classname>
```

где:
<classpath> - путь к папке с скомипилированым классом (обычно это папка bin или build в папке с вашим проэктом)
classname - полное имя класса, включая имя пакета, примеры: Test, java.sun.util.SomeClass

как вариант можно сделать привязать .class файл к java.exe

Answer (score 1):

ну и что вы предлагаете фигню всякую? надо сделать экспорт проекта в джар файл и все будет работать, как хочет топранер. В ехе оборачивать - это крайности.