# JavaFx executable jar

Tags: java, javafx

Создал jar через maven javafx проекта, но почему-то запускается только через командную строку, хотелось бы увидеть реакцию и после обычного двойного щелчка

Идея с bat не будет решением т.к. будет висеть консоль, а echo-off ее не убирает а лишь не выводит в ней команды.

Почему-то такая проблема только с javaFx в остальных случаях jar отзывается на даблклик

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Команда
assembly:assembly

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание запуска приложения java для "недалеких" пользователей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76122/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-java-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: @Dred Идея с bat не решает мою проблему т.к. консоль весит даже если есть echo off  просто не отображаются команды

Comment: Так там же не только bat. Например, 3 или 4 ответы очень хорошие.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтоб запускать десктопное GUI приложение на Java из .bat файла без отображения консольного окна, существует общепринятая практика, достаточно создать .bat файл и написать в нем:

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0 
start "run" "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw" -jar -Xmx768m "ваш .jar файл"
```

важная часть здесь:

```
start "run"
```

Если все же Вы хотите запускать приложение двумя кликами, что не рекомендуется, но оно у вас открывается как архив, у вас скорее всего не указана программа Java по умолчанию для файлов типа .jar. В таком случае советую обратить внимание на такую утилиту: [jarfix](https://jarfix.ru.softonic.com/)

Comment: Про команду start понял, по поводу кликов нет, у меня запускаются другие jar, почему-то  jar проекта javafx не реагирует

Comment: А через консоль запускается? Дополните вопрос какой командой Вы запускаете из консоли?